# Draw a border around an ImageView which has wrap_content height and width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I need to set a rectangle border around an `ImageView` on Android.
I do not know exact ratio of the image, so set height and width to `wrap_content`. The `ImageView` is limited by top and bottom views.

How to draw the border exactly around the image? Not full ImageView?

Currently it gives the following result:
[image: Result]

My XMLs.
Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/outer_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_layout_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/login_course_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/login_layout_account_fields"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/border_course_logo"
            tools:ignore="contentDescription"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/login_progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/login_layout_account_fields"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            tools:ignore="textFields">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

border_course_logo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/divider"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your's place I would change ImageView's width after downloading an image (if you use Glide or something like this).

Comment: Is there any cure using xml only?

Comment: I think it isn't

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your ImageView in the layout xml file.

Comment: `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` doesn't help